# Why ajax button calls submitForm?

Tags: 8, forms

I have no problems with using Ajax in every form element other then button. When I'm clicking this button

```
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::ajax_function',
    'wrapper' => 'my-button-wrapper',
  ],
```

it reloads the page ... well it does what would normal submit button do - calls submitForm(). And I don't need that. I need this button only to call ajax_function()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal, the submitHandler() method of your form definition will always be called UNLESS you have a custom handler attached to the submit button that is clicked. In the case of #ajax buttons, you add your own custom handler, then rebuild the form in that handler.

```
'#type' => 'submit',
'#ajax' => [
  'callback' => '::ajax_function',
  'wrapper' => 'my-button-wrapper',
],
'#submit' => ['::ajaxButtonSubmit'],
```

Then:

```
public function ajaxButtonSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
}
```

By doing this, the default submit handler is not called, and your ajax submit handler is called instead, which then ensures the form is rebuilt instead of reloaded.

Comment: There also was 'id' in '#attributes', it was interfering too

Comment: Great answer, the custom submit handler is equally important as fallback when js is not available.

Comment: Good point! ....

Comment: And unfortunately it's not working

Comment: I've used this many times on forms. It works. Re-check your code.

Comment: More to it, there has to be some value, at least '#value' => false then it calls for the callback function, at least in my case. Thanks again Jaypan